# How to fetch Image from server in windows phone

Tags: wcf, windows-phone-7, imagedownload

I want to fetch all images from server in windows phone.So i wrote these line of code in my project.

```
  { ...
 WebClient wc = new WebClient(); 
    wc.AllowReadStreamBuffering = true; 
    wc.OpenReadCompleted += new OpenReadCompletedEventHandler(wc_OpenReadCompleted); wc.OpenReadAsync(new Uri("http://......./Images/" + image1path)); 
... 
    }
```

---

```
 void wc_OpenReadCompleted(object sender, OpenReadCompletedEventArgs e)
 {
  Stream result=e.Result;
  BitmapImage bmp = new BitmapImage();
  bmp.SetSource(stream );         
}
```

Suppose there are 10 images on server then wc_OpenReadCompleted(object sender, OpenReadCompletedEventArgs e) calls 10 times but it gives result in wrong order.
I am getting all images but in wrong sequence every time.

How can I solve it?

Answer (score 0):

The way in which you get the result image depends on the image size and also on the way in which the threads are dispatched. So if you are so much interested to receive in specific manner, dispatch threads strictly according to the way you want and moreover make them download one after the other.

Comment: So @max how can i do,so you have some line  of code then please reply me.Thanks

Comment: see i am asking you as why do u want in specific order? If so give file names to each of the image and combine in order with those file names. I will come up with code soon.

Comment: Thanks @max,because i am fetching details of each photo(e.g. name age city etc) which come in right order but image is not coming such a manner and when i am combining photo with details,it mismatches.